# WCF AND ASP.NET session sharing

Tags: asp.net, ajax, wcf, client-server

Here is my case, I am working on an infrastructure for a scale able application.
I am creating a simple ASP.NET client page that consumes a WCF service with an AJAX call (simple xmlhttp object not .net script manager). 
I need the 2 to share sessions, so I have instructed the ASP.NET client application to store the session in SQL with the aspnet_regsql.exe tool.

I have checked that WCF service is receiving the same session ID that the ASP.NET client produces, but in the service the session keys container is empty.

I am under an impression that it might have something to do with the app name in the configuration, but I really don't know...

Any direction ?

Comment: WCF by default isn't "compatible" with the ASP.NET session - after all, WCF **is not** ASP.NET and by default doesn't have anything to do with the ASP.NET runtime. WCF services can (and often should) be hosted totally independent of any IIS/ASP.NET bits - WCF isn't part of nor does it depend on ASP.NET ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the answer to my problem.
I needed to change the "TempGetAppID" procedure in the SQL ASPState DB created with the "aspnet_regsql.exe" tool  to take the APP_NAME() and not the passed argument.
That made sure that all application now share the same session.
once I have made the change the WCF Service has started to be aware of sessions inserted in my asp.net application.
problem solved.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TempGetAppID]
@appName    tAppName,
@appId      int OUTPUT
AS
SET @appName = APP_NAME()
SET @appId = NULL

SELECT @appId = AppId
FROM [ASPState].dbo.ASPStateTempApplications
WHERE AppName = @appName
```

Answer (score 3):

If you **must** share ASP.NET session with WCF services, you need to check out [WCF Services and ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx) on MSDN to find out how to enable the WCF ASP.NET compatibility mode.

Mostly, it boils down to:

```
 <system.serviceModel>        
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />    
 </system.serviceModel>
```

in your WCF service's service-side config. Also, you must make sure your WCF service implementation doesn't explicitly deny the ASP.NET compatibility mode.

So your WCF service class must either allow or even require the ASP.NET compatibility:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(
       RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
public class YourService : IYourService
```

or

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(
       RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class YourService : IYourService
```

Comment: I am sorry for not detailing that but I have added the aspNetCompatibilityEnabled flag to the service config file. I have found to root of the problem my self. please view my second post.